# SPWeb.Webs, foreach and var

Tags: object-model

See below:

```
SPWeb currentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
foreach (var web in currentWeb.Webs)
{
    // web is object here - why?
}
```

`SPWebCollection` implements `IEnumerable<SPWeb>` (among other things), so why doesn't it work?

The project framework is .NET 3.5, and I have other .NET 3.5 stuff in the same code.

**Or is this just me? Can anyone reproduce?**

Comment: Are you building it in .NET 2 or greater?

Comment: Make sure in this model you dispose of things properly too. (use the try-finally method). Read this for more info: http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2008/06/disposing-sharepoint-objects-what-they.html

Comment: @Sébastien Yes, project framework is .NET 3.5. I have other .NET 3.5 stuff in my code.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't specified what your actual problem is, unless you are wondering why the variable "web" is an object. The reason it is an object is because you defined it as a "var", not an SPWeb. If you built your foreach loop like this:

```
SPWeb currentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
foreach (SPWeb web in currentWeb.Webs)
{
// web is now an SPWeb object.
}
```